# Boost ASIO slow

Tags: c++, performance, networking, boost-asio

My performance with Boost ASIO on localhost seems slow. I'm using two reads/writes per data send/receive:

```
boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer((char*)&data_size_network_byte_order, sizeof(uint32)));
boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(results->get_data(), data_size));
```

The reason is to send the size of the data first and then the data itself. Is this inefficient? If so what would be a more efficient way?

I have set no_delay to true and this helps a lot but isn't enough.

Comment: How slow is slow? What did you measure?

Comment: 20,000 requests processed in 658ms which is 30,396 requests/second (mainly asio reads & writes). This is not terrible but compared to redis-benchmark which is able to process over 66,000 requests/second I think it could be better.

Comment: The code doesn't deal with requests. At all. Do you mean you are _sending_ redis requests? How do you know when it is processed? How many threads are sending? Most likely you need just 1 thread, and using `async_` operations instead.

Comment: The redis req/sec was just for a comparison, not a perfect one at all I admin. I can try async_ operations, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First off, without measurements you're nowhere. Can you prove that it is *unnecessarily* slow?

Second, be sure to use scatter-gather and the composed write-operations supplied by ASIO. That eliminates your code as a source of inefficiency, and also generally removes room for error.

In that case

```
boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer((char*)&data_size_network_byte_order, sizeof(uint32)));
boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(results->get_data(), data_size));
```

Could be

### Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b870e47608e310f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main() {
    using namespace boost::asio;
    io_context io;
    ip::tcp::socket s(io);
    s.connect({{}, 6868});

    std::string buf1 = "hello", buf2 = "world";
    std::vector<const_buffer> bufs { buffer(buf1), buffer(buf2) };
    auto written = write(s, bufs);

    assert(written == buf1.size() + buf2.size());
}
```

This sends "helloworld", as you can see by the output of `netcat` and the fact that the assert doesn't fire.

Comment: Hi, see my comment at above in reply to janm regarding measurements (not perfect but a good indicator). Thanks for your example, but what would the corresponding read look like? The problem I had was that you don't know the size of the buffer you're reading, which is why I had two writes and two reads per buffer send/recv.

Comment: Your code shows no read. Just look under https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/buffers.html I suppose. There's no way around reading the size first indeed. Which is [why I asked/mentioned all the other things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53060584/boost-asio-slow/53061201?noredirect=1#comment93020920_53060584)

Comment: If you run into serious scalability issues (I don't think so, from your description): https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues/203 is a good hint